# Possible to Combine these Two Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am using the VBScript regular expressions engine.

I have two regular expressions:

The first one replaces non `a-zA-Z0-9` chars with a dash:

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[-{2,}]`

e.g. `...this_string?` becomes `-this-string-`

The second one removes dash chars from the beginning and/or end of the resulting string from the first replacement:

`^-+|-+$`

e.g. `-this-string-` becomes `this-string`

I have this working perfectly now, but as two separate (but nested) regex replace calls.

`r.replace("^-+|-+$", r.replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[-{2,}]+", o.Value, "-"), "")`

Is there a way to combine these two into a single regex replacement?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that didn't make any sense, disregard what I said. I don't know either how you can remove characters and replace characters in one regex. Good luck!

Comment: i think that's possible with capturing groups

Comment: The second alternative in your regex isn't doing what you think it is.  `[-{2,}]` matches `-`, `{`, `2`, `,`, or `}`.  To match two or more consecutive hyphens, you would use just `-{2,}` or `--+`.  But you don't need to; the first alternative is already handling that.

Comment: @AlanMoore - thanks for the note. I am not sure I follow. The reason I have that second portion is solely for 2 or more hyphens in a row. Yes the first matches a single hyphen, BUT when I do the replace (e.g. replace a match with a single hyphen), it replaces consecutive hyphens with the same number of hyphens. But with that extra part I have added on, it replaces groups of consecutive hyphens with a single one.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. I need to change it to this: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|-{2,}`

Comment: For what you're doing, there's no need to treat hyphens specially.  Just replace `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` with `-`, then trim the leading and trailing hyphens.  (And no, you can't do both in one `replace()`.)  The only way you could have gotten consecutive hyphens in the output is if you left the `+` off (or maybe used `*` instead).  But then *every* non-alphanumeric character would be replaced with a new hyphen, not just hyphens.

Comment: @Alan Moore - you right. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not replacing the source string "problematic" characters with a single string. You are using two different replacements (dash or empty string) depending on where the matching segment is located.

The only way to do that with only a regexp replace operation is to use a function to handle the replacement. This function will be called for each match and will determine the correct replacement for each case

```
Option Explicit 

Dim originalString    
    originalString = "...this___---is----a-----string?"

Dim convertedString

    Function determineReplacement(matchString, position, sourceString)
        If position = 0 Or (position + Len(matchString)) = Len(sourceString) Then 
            determineReplacement = ""
        Else
            determineReplacement = "-"
        End If 
    End Function 

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"
        .Global = True 
        .IgnoreCase = False
        convertedString = .Replace(originalString,GetRef("determineReplacement"))
    End With 

    WScript.Echo originalString
    WScript.Echo convertedString
```

Comment: hmm, I do it all in one line and it works... I was just wondering if there was a way to achieve the same thing with a single expression replace.

Comment: @robarwebservices, as indicated, the problem is that your replacement is not only one string (you use either a empty string or a dash) or something that is included in the source string (that can be handled by capture groups). The only way I see to do all the required operations inside the source string with **only one regexp `.Replace` call** (without additional operations in the string) is the indicated one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach:

Instead of trying to match the non alpha numeric chars, how about matching the rest and then joining the matches array together with a `-`?

Pattern:

```
  ([A-Za-z0-9])
```

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-",Regex.Matches("...this_string?", "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)").Cast<object>()));
```

[image]

Sorry: Code is C#, you can translate it to VB though!

Comment: Interesting. It is still two steps though... it is just that one of the steps changed from a regex replace to a string concatenation, which, off the top of my head, would be more expensive.

Comment: well, it's one regex and that combines the two into one... hmm the op did not mention anything about performance did he? using regex by itself is expensive i think